# SQL query adding a duplicate rows on every run in php

Tags: php, sql

Below piece of code on every execution is creating two rows. Just for testing purpose I commented out php variables and replace them with hardcoded value like '1', '3' etc in `VALUE` clause of `INSERT` query. I could not find out the exact cause, so putting here the entire code. Here `TaskID` is Auto incremented column.

```
/* CONNECT TO DATABASE TO ADD THIS TASK IN PT_TASK TABLE */
if ($ConnectStatus) {
    echo '1';
        $Query = "INSERT INTO PT_TASKS (TaskID, ParentID, Title, AssignedTo, Category, Status, Zone, Created, CreatedTime, LastModified, ProgressPercent, Notes, StartDate, TargetDate, ActualStart, ActualEnd)
          VALUES (' ','12449','3','1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1')";    
         // VALUES (' ','$ParentID','$Title','$AssignedTo','$Categories','$Status','$Zone','$Created','$CreatedTime','$LastModified','$ProgressPercent','$Notes','$PlannedStart','$PlannedEnd','$ActualStart','$ActualEnd')";   
        if (!mysql_query($Query,$con))
              {
              die('Error:  ' . mysql_error());
              }
              else
              {
              echo "updated1";
              }

        $Query_result = mysql_query($Query);

}
 else {
     ?><div class="Error">Database Connection Failed. Can not create this project. </div><?php

}
```

Whenever I refresh this page two rows get added in table `PT_TASKS`. Ideally only one row should get added in `PT_TASKS`. Not sure what mistake I am making. Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take out the last

```
$Query_result = mysql_query($Query);
```

Since you are already executing the query before that as

```
if (!mysql_query($Query,$con))
```